# setup.py: change where will build, dist and egg will be created

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have a setup.py for my project and every time I run:
python setup.py install 
it creates:
build, dist and egg under the same directory.
How can I make it to create these in a different directory?

Comment: Why is the default location a problem for you?

Comment: Because I have multiple machines use this location to install the project at the same time and when they do the installation fails.

Comment: Why do multiple machines share the same location and why don't you use `pip`?

Comment: Maybe you should `sdist` on the coordinator and `pip install` the resulting archive on each node.